# NFC POS Terminal Development

Tags: sdk, terminal, nfc

Im interested on develop an Payment System able to receive data from a real NFC POS Terminal,
as far as i know, Ingenico have an SDK but is only available to USA for Tellium Students.

What are the best NFC POS Terminal available to develop with SDK ?

Any advice is greatly appreciated !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

https://www.terminalsimulator.com/

From mastercard might be a place to start. I work for a company that is developing a payment system in the UK and there is much more to it than it seems.

Answer (score 0):

In the financial institution I work for, we do like testing NFC transactions with VivoPay terminals and our own C# in-house application. VivoPay terminals are developed by Vivotech and they notably support PayPass and PayWave.

[Here are Vivotech authorized distributors in USA.](https://www.vivotek.com/where-to-buy/7/united-states) Note that many other countries are supported.

[I also found some on Amazon USA.](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=vivopay)

[The SDK is available at this link with a registered account.](https://w3.vivotek.com/sdk/)

Comment: It´s been 5 years ! Do you have any link to investigate ?

Comment: Sure, I added some links into my answer.